# How to write a WorkdayDiff date function in Power Query M Language

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I am trying to create a custom function which calculates the workday difference between two dates. I have done the same function in SSRS:

```
Public Function WorkdayDiff(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date) As Date

  Return Datediff("ww", StartDate, EndDate, vbMonday) + 
         Datediff("ww", StartDate, EndDate, vbTuesday) + 
         Datediff("ww", StartDate, EndDate, vbWednesday) + 
         Datediff("ww", StartDate, EndDate, vbThursday) + 
         Datediff("ww", StartDate, EndDate, vbFriday)

End Function
```

I tryed to do the same now in Power Query M language but it keeps me saying:

> Type is not defined.

This is my code in the advanced editor in Power BI:

```
(DateStart as Date, DateEnd as Date) as Date =>

let
    WorkdayDiff = Datediff("ww",DateStart ,DateEnd, vbMonday) +
                Datediff("ww",DateStart ,DateEnd, vbTuesday) + 
                Datediff("ww",DateStart ,DateEnd, vbWednesday) + 
                Datediff("ww",DateStart ,DateEnd, vbThursday) + 
                Datediff("ww",DateStart ,DateEnd, vbFriday)
in
    WorkdayDiff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several issues.

The reason you're getting `Type not defined` is that M is case-sensitive and you need to use `date` rather than `Date` when referring to data types. M also does not have a `Datediff` function or understand what `vbMonday` means. You have to use M functions rather than just pasting in SSRS code and hoping it works.

Here's a possible implementation in M in the style of [this post](https://www.poweredsolutions.co/2018/03/05/calculate-days-dates-using-power-query/).

```
let
    WorkdayDiff = (StartDate as date, EndDate as date) as number =>
    let
        DateList = List.Dates(StartDate, Number.From(EndDate - StartDate) + 1, #duration(1,0,0,0)),
        RemoveWeekends = List.Select(DateList, each Date.DayOfWeek(_, Day.Monday) < 5),
        CountDays = List.Count(RemoveWeekends)
    in
        CountDays
in
    WorkdayDiff
```